# Remove "All categories" from searchbar dropdown

Tags: categories, search

I have been struggling with this and could not find a clear answer online.

Will putting a product search bar I have a dropdown visible with all the categories you can search in.
I would just like to keep only the categories and remove the "all categories" option.

You can see the current search I would like to fix here :
https://compare-tech.fr

Thank you to anyone who will be able to help :)

Comment: Welcome Antoine!  Please answer a question or two, so we might provide more accurate recommendations.   1. Did you code this search, or are you using a default Wordpress widget?  2. If you coded this, would you please provide a sample of your code, so we can advise you how to modify it.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. 
This is the default wordpress widget.

Answer (score 0):

This list can be modified using WooCommerce filters.  However, without a thorough testing I could not find a specific filter to help you. You might [check the API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Widget_Product_Categories.html#11-301) for a better answer.

Meanwhile, I have used this CSS snippet to successfully hide the "All Categories" entry from the drop-down selector:

```
li.option[data-value=''] {
    display: none;
}
```

This will only prevent users from selecting "All Categories" again.  It will not prevent your page from defaulting to "All Categories".

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you for your help ! We are halfway there. The "All categories" only shows before anything else is selected. So I just need to change the default selected category.

I used this :
function wp_dropdown_categories( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'selected'          => 2,
    );

But it crashed my website.. that might not be it.
Can anyone see my mistake ?